# How to get Actual IPAddr from DDNS hostname

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using Dyndns service for my PC.  This allows me to get my PC's current Wan IPAddr from my ISP.

say I can use below WinForm app code to get the IPAddr by passing in this hostname  example : Marina.dyndns.biz

```
public static void DoGetHostEntry(string hostname)
{
    IPHostEntry host;

    host = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname);

    Console.WriteLine("GetHostEntry({0}) returns:", hostname);

    foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
    }
}
```

My PC link to a router which uses local ISP service.

Q1. Is this returned Wan IPaddr refered to my Router's External IPAddr ?

Q2. What if  I have fixed an IPAddr for the PC say 192.168.1.90?  then what is the returned IPAddr refered to?

Q3. How do I do in Windows Phone 7.1 Mango version to get my PC's IPAddr with above code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A while back I used a similar service however it installed itself as a service and used to monitor the network for changes. The way it should work is by making calls to its server and checking the ip request is coming from.

The router itself has the WAN and internally uses LAN IPs to then do a NAT for comms over WAN.

The WAP IP is the external router IP that is given out by the ISP

When you do a Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname) you will get 192.168.1.90 which is the LAN IP of you PC.. not the WAN IP.. WAN ip is accessible to Dyndns but not to our code / OS itself directly.

You can't access / scan for IP address for other devices from #WP&

Comment: Thanks. I have Dyndns Acct. When I use the above code, I get my WAN IPAddr for my Router but this is Windows form app. My problem is how do I code in WP as there is no DNS class for wp7.1 Thanks